# Open special section of a local HTML file in default browser

Tags: c#, url, process

I want to open the documentation, which is stored in a single local html file, when the user clicks on certain wpf controls. Normally, the file can be navigated using HTML sections, and links like `file:///C:/Users/uname/Desktop/Tool/DOCUMENTATION.html#section` work (page is automatically scrolled so the section is in view) when I copy them into the address field, but when I try to open the browser by starting a new process using that same URL, the section at the end always gets removed and the page is shown from the top. This is the code I use to open the browser:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = "/C start " + "file://" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "DOCUMENTATION.html" + "#" + section,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            });
```

I first tried to open the file directly as a new process (`Process.Start("path\to\file.html")`) but I obviously cannot auto-navigate to sections that way.

Is there any way to achieve this "focus" on a certain section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in 2010, this question was [answered as follows](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c41dc235-9c02-4cd8-8707-6912b3898add/open-local-html-file-in-browser-and-jump-to-an-anchor?forum=vbgeneral) (in VisualBasic):

```
    Dim BrowserRegistryString As String = My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("\http\shell\open\command\").GetValue("").ToString
    Dim DefaultBrowserPath As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(BrowserRegistryString, "(\"".*?\"")").Captures(0).ToString
    Dim LocalURL As String = "file:///C:/users/matt/desktop/page.htm#test"
    Process.Start(DefaultBrowserPath, LocalURL)
```

Migrated to C#, by [Jakob Tinhofer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10619713/jakob-tinhofer):

```
string val = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"\http\shell\open\command")!.GetValue("")!.ToString()!;
pathToDefaultBrowser = val.Substring(1).Split('\"')[0];
```

The `cmd` shell does not pass the `#test` anchor tag, because the tag does not belong to the object to be started by the shell. Therefore, you probably have to explicitely start a browser. Either you encode your favorite browser, or you extract the default browser from the registry as shown in the example.

If you would prefer `firefox` or `chrome`, you can simply use:

```
cmd.exe /C start firefox file:///C:/users/matt/desktop/page.htm#test
```

or

```
cmd.exe /C start chrome file:///C:/users/matt/desktop/page.htm#test
```

Windows [does know](https://www.howtogeek.com/689159/how-to-open-mozilla-firefox-using-command-prompt-on-windows-10/) where to find them. But this does not work for every browser.

Comment: Thanks! This works, interestingly it now opens IE (when using just the link it used to open chrome). This is how it looks for me in C#, if you want to update your question for other C# ppl that need this: ```string val = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"\http\shell\open\command")!.GetValue("")!.ToString()!;
            pathToDefaultBrowser = val.Substring(1).Split('\"')[0];```